# NetBeans (Java) - loading additional .java files

Tags: java, netbeans

So I had an assignment to write a program for the game `Othello/Reversi`. I used NetBeans. Now the teacher sent us a `"ReversiGUI.java"` file that uses my own `ReversiPlay.java` and loads it onto a GUI so that I can test the game with my bots etc.

If I use the regular `javac ReversiGUI.java` and then run `java ReversiGUI` this works very well. However, it would be much easier for me to run the GUI from NetBeans, because I am getting some errors in the GUI, and I want to fix my code, but the info from the command line is very minimal (type of exception and line number). In NetBeans I will be able to debug and see which specific values are causing the problem.

I tried loading the GUI file into my `ReversiPlay` project, but every time the line `ReversiPlay.someMethod` is used, NetBeans says it does not recognize the symbol. So I'm guessing there's a specific way of loading the `ReversiGUI.java` file in NetBeans but I have no idea how to do it..

Any ideas?

Comment: 1) Are the files in the same folder?  2) If not, did you use an `import` statement for the location of the `ReversiPlay` class?

Comment: I have tried adding the 'ReversiGUI.java' file to the 'src' folder of the project in NetBean (alongside the 'ReversiPlay.java' file. It still has all the red lines under each call to 'ReversiPlay.someMethod' with the same error. Also, for some reason the first 'import' line of the GUI file is also red and it says 'Incorrect package' (the line is 'import java.awt.Color;').

Comment: This is how it looks right now: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-4vUrIGZBqoQV9za0JTSXdhYms/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `NetBeans` expects a package declaration, unlike command line.  At the top of both your files put the following line:

```
package reversiplay;
```

That should fix your errors.  Hope this helps!